# How to access the organization from within a plugin?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I'm reading some really ill-written code and my brains just shut down, mostly due to frustration, so the question is probably an easy one.

I'm in a plugin and I need to create a new instance of entity *Blobb*. Given that I have the query expression done, how do I execute it? Do I have to go through creating the *OrganizationServiceProxy* object or can I use the *IServiceProvider* instance sent into *Execute* method? I'm using it to get the context (i.e. *IPluginExecutionContext* typed object) but I can't find the service with a method to execute my query expression.

Comment: Please port your code.

Comment: Sorry its just a type. I mean post your code not port :) Glad it helped you.

Comment: @Scorpion What **type**? Naa, I know what you mean. Just joking. Kind of funny when one makes a typo in *typo*.   :)

Comment: Oh god.... my typo problem... :) I should join english.stackexchange.com as well :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for this. You can use Execute by using `LocalPluginContext`.

```cs
public class OrgPlugin: Plugin
{
    public OrgPlugin()
        : base(typeof(OrgPlugin))
    {
        base.RegisteredEvents.Add(new Tuple<int, string, string, Action<LocalPluginContext>>(20, "Create", "account", new Action<LocalPluginContext>(ExecuteOrgPlugin)));
    }

    protected void ExecuteOrgPlugin(LocalPluginContext localContext)
    {
        Blobb blobb = new Blobb();
        blobb["new_name"] = "abc";
        // Other attributes here
        localContext.OrganizationService.Execute(blobb);
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

You can extract the  `OrganizationService` from `localContext.OrganizationService`

```cs
IOrganizationService service = localContext.OrganizationService;
```